# Using a non-standard location for avahi services

Tags: linux, configuration, readonly, avahi

I want to use avahi on a system with a read-only rootfs where `/etc` is not writable.

I can start `avahi-daemon` with the `-f` option to specify a non-standard location for the `avahi-daemon.conf` file (default location is `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`). However I can't find any way to specify a non-standard location for the service definitions (default location is `/etc/avahi/services`). Is there any option for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Avahi does not provide any configuration option for searching for service definitions in a non-standard location (other than rebuilding with a custom `--prefix`, but that obviously has other implications). In case someone else needs this, these are the options I've found:

- Symlink /etc/avahi/services to a different directory. For this to work, the avahi daemon must be started with the `--no-chroot` option; otherwise it will not be able to reach out of the chroot jail.
- Bind mount a different directory on /etc/avahi/services. This does not require that `--no-chroot` is used.

Both options work fine.

Answer (score -1):

(Using a answer window as it has more formatting options)

Note that Avahi service definitions allow wildcards. This might be adequate to allow the same definition on multiple hosts, thus allowing read-only /etc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?><!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
  <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h</name>
  <service>
    <type>_ssh._tcp</type>
    <port>22</port>
  </service>
</service-group>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question ?